# UIScrollview not scrolling/dragging but properties are set up correctly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have subclassed uitableview and faced a problem. The table stopped scrolling. However, all the properties are set up correctly:

```
.bounces = yes
.shouldalwaysbouncevertical = yes
.scrollenabled = yes
.userinteractionenabled = yes
```

Furthermore, table content size is bigger than its bound position. The view receives touches but doesn't handle any scrollViewDidScroll, scrollViewWillBeginDragging... methods. I have ho views above table. But actually, it handles taps. Have no ideas of what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done in your subclass? Does a normal tableView used in the same place scroll or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the scroll view content size in viewWillAppear method.

Ex --
contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.fram.size.width, tableView.fram.size.height);